# Warning: PDO::prepare() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, execute, prepare

I have been trying to convert a old `mysql` too `pdo` as I am trying to learn how `pdo` works, I have been working on this one file for hours now busting my head and can not figure out what is wrong, and I'm sure its a lot.

```
try{
    $check_user_data = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$username'");
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($check_user_data);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result->bind_result($username);
    $data_exists = ($check_user_data->fetchColumn() > 0) ? true : false;
    if($data_exists = false){
        $final_report.="This username does not exist..";
    }else{
        $get_user_data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($get_user_data['password'] == $password){
            $start_idsess = $_SESSION['username'] = "".$get_user_data['username']."";
            $start_passsess = $_SESSION['password'] = "".$get_user_data['password']."";
            $final_report.="You are about to be logged in, please wait a few moments.. <meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='2; URL=members.php'/>";
        }
    }
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row){
    }
    $dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Also getting a fatal

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object
```

Not sure if the fatal is related to the warning or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, change these two lines:

```
$check_user_data = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$username'");
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($check_user_data);
```

to:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = :username");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
```

This makes use of the parameter feature of prepared statements, which prevents SQL injection.

Next, PDO doesn't have a `bind_result` method, that's part of MySQLI. To get the results, you should do:

```
$get_user_data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$data_exists = ($get_user_data !== false);
```

You should then remove the call to `$stmt->fetch` in the `else` block, because it will try to get the next row of results.

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty` Everything else works great. Ill post changes in a new answer.

Comment: Is that happening on the line with `$dbh->query($sql)`? Have you assigned `$sql`?

Comment: Had this in there don't think i need it so I took it out, Not sure why it was there. `foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)`, Everything works thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The fatal is definitely related to the warning; you are passing the results of `$dbh->query()` (which is a PDOStatementObject) into `$dbh->prepare`, causing `$dbh->prepare` to return something which is not an object.

Just move the SQL into the `$dbh->prepare` call and get rid of the `$dbh->query()` entirely.

Answer (score 0):

For people who might come over here my problem was a bit different i was trying to enable a filter on doctrine/symfony project and accidentally made a mistake on the following line :

```
$filter->setParameter($name, $someObject);
```

and when i called the function `getParameter($name)` in `addFilterConstraint` function i got the same error

> Warning: PDO::prepare() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

And later on i found the mistake. the fix would be to replace the setParameter second input from `$someObject` to `$someString` something like this:

```
$filter->setParameter($name, 'some string which is the real value you want to get later');
```